# How to get a cell text in a c1flexgrid

Tags: c#, wpf, c1flexgrid

Can anybody help me?

I need to get a text from a cell in the c1flexgrid when I click it.
I use this code:

```
private void CmdSaveCellContent_Executed(EventParameters param)
{
    C1FlexGrid dg = param.Sender as C1FlexGrid;
    Point mp = Mouse.GetPosition(dg);
    HitTestInfo hti = dg.HitTest(mp);
    if (hti.Column == -1 || hti.Row == -1 || dg.Rows.Count <= hti.Row) return;
    var celltext = dg.Cells[hti.Row, hti.Column];

...
}
```

It works if cell contains text information. But if cell contains Enum, visually I see text, but in the celltext variable I get int value ("0" or "2" for instance).

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following line of code in the `AfterSelChange` event of the `C1Flexgrid` :

```
MessageBox.Show(Me, "Value of cell " & Me.C1FlexGrid1.Row.ToString() & "/" & Me.C1FlexGrid1.Col.ToString() & ": " & Me.C1FlexGrid1(Me.C1FlexGrid1.Row, Me.C1FlexGrid1.Col).ToString())
```

Regards,
Mohita